# Commuting from Frankfurt to Bad Homburg

Tags: public-transport, germany, bicycles, frankfurt, commute

I'll be doing a work trip to Germany during 2 or 3 months, and I have to get to my job from Frankfurt to Bad Homburg, I haven't been able to get precise online info about bus and train ticket prices (some websites say 2€, 3€ or 6€). I want to know the cost of these tickets in order to decide if it's better to get a second hand bike during my stay or if in the long term it'll be no difference in making it to public transportation. This must take into consideration that due to the fact of being a commuting journey, I'd need two tickets (at least, I guess)

Taking this into account, if the bike is the best option to go, I'd like to know a safe place where can I get a decent second hand one, neither so expensive nor so simple, my goal is not a super bike, just a good one, I'd like something nice and at a affordable price.

Answer (score 2):

The monthly ticket is 133,80€. If you don't care too much about quality and comfort, you can even get a new bicycle for the price of two monthly tickets. A single fare is 4,80€ or you can also get a day ticket for 9,35€, which is slightly cheaper than two single tickets.

The monthly tickets are paper tickets and for tax or accounting purposes, the ticket itself is valid as a receipt. You don't get an additional receipt when buying these tickets.

Comment: Second hand bikes should be available for the price of a single monthly ticket. You may have to shop around or even ask around.